# web app startup warning:No MyBatis mapper was found in ... ,Please check your configuration

Tags: spring, mybatis

My configuration is:

```
spring-4.2.3
mybatis-3.3.0
mybatis-spring-1.2.3
```

mapper looks like:

```
package com.vsi.idp.map.server.mapper;
//imports...
public interface SeniorMapper extends BaseMapper<Long, Senior>
{
   @Results({...})
   @Select(...)
   public List<Senior> query(...);
}
```

**ServiceImpl** looks like:

```
package com.vsi.idp.map.server;
//imports...
@Service("querySenior")
public class SeniorQueryServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements     SeniorQueryService
{
    @Autowired
    SeniorMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public List<Senior> query(Address address, String careType){...}
}
```

**applicationContext.xml** looks like:

```
<beans ... default-lazy-init="true">
   <!-- MyBatis Mapper Interfaces -->
   <mybatis:scan base-package="com.vsi.idp.map.server.mapper" />

   //other configurations
</beans>
```

Spock **unit test** looks like below,and **runs as expected**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:war/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
public class SeniorQueryServiceImplTest extends Specification{

  @Autowired
  SeniorQueryServiceImpl service

  def "query by full address"(){
     //blabla
  }
}
```

But when start web application,I got this warning:

```
WARNING: No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.vsi.idp.map.server.mapper]' package. Please check your configuration.
```

So,how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**it is a gwt web application,full error stack is:

```
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started Nov 23, 2015 7:12:29 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Nov 23 19:12:29 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy Nov 23, 2015 7:12:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] Nov 23, 2015 7:12:29 PM org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner doScan
WARNING: No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.vsi.idp.map.server.mapper]' package. Please check your configuration.Nov 23, 2015 7:12:30 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Module setup completed in 1698 ms
Nov 23, 2015 7:12:30 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1557 ms
```

Comment: please show us the full stacktrace. possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829318/spring-4-mybatis-integration-issue-using-java-8

Comment: Hello,full stacktrace added

Answer (score 5):

```
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.vsi.idp.map.server.mapper")
```

you can try add it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `MapperScannerConfigurer` in applicationContext.xml? If so, please delete it.

I have the following config in my applicationContext.xml, and when I deleted it, the warning has gone.

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.james.reg.mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```